# Cause for audio disturbances in bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

Having connected my blaupunkt car radio to my android smartphone via bluetooth(connection established signs on both devices) instead of played audio, I currently get the very noise you see here. Note the frequencies and that its volume goes in and out.

[image]

Sometimes for a short period of time, audio comes through, to then be replaced by those noises again.

What is the likely cause?

Here's an amplified version:

[image]

Comment: Are these diagrams showing the audio signal or the Bluetooth frequencies? Have you tried other Bluetooth devices to determine if the problem is caused by the car radio or the Android phone? What Bluetooth audio codec is used (you should be able to see only one entry in the BT audio codec list in developer option on Android).

Comment: The audio signal.

Comment: Please answer the rest of the questions.  More information is required.  How far is the phone from radio?  Is Bluetooth built into the radio or are you using a dongle?  Does another phone work with it? How did you measure this noise?